# Node.JS and express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I have a problem with my POST function. When I press the **log in button**, I get the message:

> Cannot POST /login

I have no idea what to do. I hope one of you could help me \(^-^\)

Here is my Code:

```js
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const { check } = require('express-validator')
    const http = require('http')
    const port = 3000

    app.use(express.static('./public', {index: 'login.html'}))
    app.use(express.urlencoded());

    // Routing
    let loginRouter = express.Router()

    app.use('/login', loginRouter)

    loginRouter.all('/login', function (req, res) {
        console.log('POST')
        console.log(req.body)
        console.log('GET')
        console.log(req.query)
    })
    app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('listen on http://localhost:' + port)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/login">
            <div>
                <label for="user">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="userpw">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="userpw" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: where is the routes for `loginRouter` ? you haven't defined any

Answer (score 2):

You registered `loginRouter` as middleware at path `/login` using:

```
app.use('/login', loginRouter)
```

This means any path you listen in router would become sub-path to `/login`.

So, actual link becomes `/login/login` in your case.

You may want to remove above middleware and retry.

Comment: ok, I have comment `app.use('login', loginRouter)` but now it keeps loading :/

Comment: Since you are not sending any response back to client, call `res.end()` at end of your function.